# Symfony mode prod: pass a jsonfile to an ajax request not working

Tags: php, ajax, json, symfony, production-environment

Hy guys,

I'm pulling my hairs. I have fields in a form which are filled with an ajax request.

It's working well in dev mode . But in prod mode, it's not working, the server send a response well, but the program don't go to the succes function but the error one. 
I'm doing an ajax request with datatype: 'json'.

The problem come from the server/php part, the response in prod looks like that:

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-deprecated xe-scream' dir='ltr'       border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'> 
<<... and 30 lines more like that..>>
</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-bundle\Doctrine\Bundle   \DoctrineBundle\Registry.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\Registry.php<b>:</b>71</td></tr>
</table></font>
[{"id":1,"nom":"Wakeboard"},{"id":2,"nom":"Surf"},{"id":6,"nom":"Skate"}]
```

So the data appear at the end but there are lot of codes line that i don't know from where they come?

It's clearly a problem of json in mode prod with symfony, for me, but i didn't find issue yet.

Hope i was clear, sorry if it's not well said i'm french. :)

I put my server code here:

```
public function rempliAction()
{
$request = $this->getRequest();

if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) // pour vérifier la présence d'une requete Ajax
{
    $id = $request->request->get('id');
    $selecteur = $request->request->get('select');

    if ($id != null)
    {   
        $data = $this->getDoctrine()
                     ->getEntityManager()
                     ->getRepository('sdzBikindBundle:'.$selecteur)
                     ->$selecteur($id);


        return new JsonResponse($data); 
    }
}
return new Response("Nonnn ....");        
}
```

Thank you in advance. David

Comment: Sounds like you've misconfigured your production server with XDebug installed and [set to scream](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/all_settings). Also, look more carefully at the HTML it's spitting out: you've said "30 more lines like that", but what you've pasted is just the styling; read on, and you'll find the actual error/notice.

Comment: Did you clear your cache for prod env? `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: Hello, thank you for help. I did a php app/check.php and seen that i need apc. I also need to get a more recent version of php. For the 30 line, you say it's the styling, but in dev, there's no styling... For me, it's just the json which has to be sent no? And a difference between dev and prod when i use the form and so the ajax request, is that the answer in firebug in network>XHR dont show a json item in prod env wheras there is on in dev env. And yes i cleared the cache in prod env

Comment: Hi, finally i fixed it. It was because i use ->getEntityManager() instead of getManager. I took the code from internet and didn't noticed that point. And the thing is that getEntityManager() is depreciated since symfony 2.1 . And it works in dev env but not in prod. Which is little bit disturbing and little bit hard to fix.